# How does simple segregated storage pre-allocate lists of fixed block sizes?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, virtual-memory

I'm learning dynamic memory allocation, and still a little bit confusing with some details.
We know that s segregated storage, is to maintain multiple free lists, where each list holds blocks that are roughly the same size:

[image]

So one popular approach is **simple segregated storage** that pre-allocates lists of fixed block sizes, where a list occupies full VM page(s):
[image]

Below is my questions:

Q1: How does simple segregated storage pre-allocate lists of fixed block sizes? Does it:

a) pre-allocates lists for **all** different sizes. e.g. I only want to `malloc` 8 bytes but it also create virtual pages(vp) for lists of blocks that are 8, 16, 32, 64 etc bytes, all in once.

b) only pre-allocates for the size users require. e.g. I `malloc` 16 bytes, only the virtual page for 16 bytes is created.

Q2: If the b statment in the question one is correct, that means vp can be in any random order, so the first vp doesn't necessarily for the least size which is 8 byte block. e.g. the first vp could be for 64 byte block, the second vp could be for 8 byte block, the third vp could be for 16 byte block ..etc?

Answer (score 0):

> How does simple segregated storage pre-allocate lists of fixed block sizes?

Well, that's a purely implementational detail, isn't it? It does not really matter if the allocator decides to pre-allocate everything, if it only pre-allocates pages for requested sizes, or if it's configurable to do one or the other. There is no correct answer to this question.

> If the b statment in the question one is correct, that means vp can be in any random order

Not really. The allocator can have as many supporting structures as it needs, exactly to manage situations like this.

For example, it could have an array of pointers to pages for block sizes that are different powers of two:

```c
void *pages[10] = {NULL};
// Index i holds a pointer to pages for blocks of size 2^(i+3)

void *allocate(size_t size) {
    unsigned index;

    if (s <= (2 << 3)) // up to 8 bytes
        index = 0;
    else if (s <= (2 << 4)) // up to 16 bytes
        index = 1;
    else if (s <= (2 << 5)) // up to 32 bytes
        index = 2;
    else if (s <= (2 << 6)) // up to 64 bytes
        index = 3;
    // ...

    if (pages[index] == NULL)
        pages[index] = allocate_memory_page();

    // Check free lists...
    // Return a block from pages[index]...
}
```